# Can/could with please

Tags: modal-verbs

When talking about requests, permission, favours and asking for information should I use "please" in my sentences with both *can* and *could*?

1."Can/could we look words up in a dictionary, please?"

2. "Can/could I speak to Gerry, please?"

3."Can/could I have your passport, please?"

4."Can/could I have my passport, please?"

5."Can/could I have these postcards, please?"

6."Tom, could/can  I borrow your umbrella, please?"

7."Can/could  you open the door, please?"

8."Can/could you wait a moment, please?"

Comment: _Please_ always adds an extra note of politeness.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, do you mean it's not compulsory to use it in each sentence I posted, but it would add an extra note of politeness in each?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was implying.

Comment: You could also add _please_ after sentences with _will_ or _would_ like _Will/would you shut the door after you please_